# web os application connecting MYSQL server through VPN

Tags: mysql, client-server, vpn, webos, authentication

I'm trying to develop an application that verifies the user name and password on VPN server and if success it has to give the access to the MYSQL server. can any one give me logic for this and if any working examples are appreciated. i tried google on this topic i got some information but i feel that I'm missing some thing, so any help please.

thank you in advance

Comment: Do you have something specific that you tried, thought it would work, and then didn't work?  It's easier to help you on Stack Overflow if we have something specific to go off of (unless you get lucky and someone happens to read your question who has already done exactly the same thing).

Comment: @ Gordon Worley: thank you very much for quick reply, actually i just wanted to know how to do it then i will start an application. i wrote a basic application which takes the values from a login form and send to a particular url, i wanted to know what heppen's 
on the server and how does it navigate to mysql server.
thank you for any help in advance.